# How to correctly combine DateListPlot and Plot outputs with Show command?

Tags: plotting

I'm writing a module on population dynamics for my elementary differential equations class's MMA lab.  I am pulling in the US population data with no trouble:

```
cd = CountryData["US", {"Population", {1790 , 2000}}]
```

Then the plot goes smoothly:

```
rp = DateListPlot[cd, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
```

yielding:

[image: ![US Population Plot](http://imgur.com/gallery/aS1I1)]

Then I solve the Malthusian model using the 1790 census as my initial condition:

```
malthus = DSolve[{p'[t] == k p[t], p[1790] == 3.93*10^6}, p[t], t]
```

and find the growth constant using the 2000 census:

```
Solve[(malthus[[1, 1, 2]] /. t -> 2000) == 281.42*10^6, k]
```

and plot it too:

```
malthusplot = Plot[malthus[[1, 1, 2]], {t, 1790, 2000}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]
```

[image: Multhusian Plot]

However, when I attempt to display these two graphs together the result is a correct display of whichever plot is listed first in the Show command, and the other plot is displayed as either a vertical or horizontal line.  My best guess is that time series data does not play well with others.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The units of the time values used by `DateListPlot` and `Plot` are different. The former uses seconds, with the initial time fixed in on the first of January 1900,

```
cd["Times"] // Short

(* {-3471206400, -3155673600, -2997907200, -2840140800, 
    <<122>>, 3092601600, 3124137600, 3155673600} *)
```

It reinterprets them as years only for the ticks labels. The latter symbol uses years for the time values:

```
(times = First@ Cases[malthusplot, Line[list_] :> list[[All, 1]], Infinity]) // Short

(* {1790., 1790.06, <<73>>, 1999.93, 2000.} *)
```

A possible way is then to convert the time values of the output `DateListPlot` to years, and first call `malthusplot` in `Show` so as to use the unit years for both graphics:

```
rpBis = rp /. Line[list_] :> Line[MapAt[DateValue[#, "Year"] &, list, {All, 1}]];

Show[malthusplot, rpBis]
```

[image]

---

The choice of the initial time 1st of January 1900 for the seconds also explains why the vertical line in `Show[rp, malthusplot]` is located at `1900`.

The values given by `times` (see definition above) are interpreted as seconds by `DateListPlot` and then converted to years for the ticks labels:

```
DateString /@ MinMax[DateObject /@ times]
(* {"Mon 1 Jan 1900 00:29:50", "Mon 1 Jan 1900 00:33:19"} *)
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks, Xavier, for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @ChrisB Glad this is useful. The converse approach is to modify the other plot with `malthusplotBis = malthusplot /. 
  Line[list_] :> Line[MapAt[(# - 1900) 31536000 &, list, {All, 1}]]`, and then evaluate `Show[rp, malthusplotBis]`.

Comment: @ChrisB and @xavier  Don't forget that `cd` has a `"Dates"` property as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

The ordinates of the two plots are inconsistent in that `cd` is measured in seconds, and `malthusplot` is measured in years.  Using the conversion factor, `3.154 10^7` gives,

```
dd = cd; dd[[2, 2]] = N[dd[[2, 2]]/(3.154 10^7) + 1900];
dp = ListLinePlot[dd, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[malthusplot, dp]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, bbgodfrey.  That's a nice efficient fix for the disagreement.

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) and other functions in the [`Units`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html) guide.

Solve Malthus with quantities.

```
qMalthus = 
 DSolve[{p'[t] == k p[t], p[Quantity[1790, "Years"]] == Quantity[3.93*10^6, "People"]}, 
  p[t], t]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Growth constant with quantities.

```
qSol = Solve[(p[t] /. qMalthus /. t -> Quantity[2000, "Years"]) == 
         Quantity[281.42*10^6, "People"], k]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The function with quantities is:

```
p[t] /. First@qMalthus /. First@qSol
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

When we input `t` as a `"Years"` `Quantity` then its unit will cancel with the `per years` ( `1 / "Years"` ) and leave a `"People"` `Quantity`.

A data series compatible with [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) can be obtained by a [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) for the year and the `"People"` quantities. Use [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html) to extract the year value from the `t` quantities.

```
(qRes = Table[{DateObject@QuantityMagnitude@{t}, 
               p[t] /. First@qMalthus /. First@qSol}, 
          {t, Quantity[1790, "Years"], Quantity[2000, "Years"]}]) // Short
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
qMalthusPlot = DateListPlot[qRes, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which can be given directly to `Show` with `rp` as defined in the OP.

```
Show[rp, qMalthusPlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Before all these fancy newfangled computrons including units in calculations was a good partial check that you had gotten the workings of your model correct.

Hope this helps.